# How to add a custom class or id to a custom display suite

Tags: display-suite

I've created my custom display suite field and i it works ok, but i would like to add a custom div class or a custom div id,

[image]
here is my code

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\breadcrumbs\Plugin\DsField;

use Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsField\DsFieldBase;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

/**
 *
 * @DsField(
 *   id = "breadcrumbsDS",
 *   title = @Translation("breadcrumbs"),
 *   entity_type = "node",
 *   provider = "breadcrumbs",
 *   ui_limit = {"article|*"}
 * )
 */
class breadcrumbsDS extends DsFieldBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(){
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $nid = $node->id();
      $term = Term::load($node->get('field_secciones')->target_id);
      $name = $term->getName();
      $breadcrumbs = '<div id="breadcrumbsDS"><div class="breadcrumbs home">Home</div><div class="breadcrumbs '.$name.'">'.$name.'</div></div>';
    }
    return array(
      '#markup' => $breadcrumbs,
      '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => ['custom-css-class']]  
    );
  }
}
```

Could you please help me?
regards.

Comment: '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => ['custom-css-class']]

Comment: hi @MykolaVeriga thank you, but it does not work :(

Comment: How did you use this? Please change the question for show us that